# How can I use a UITextField and convert it into a double?

Tags: formatting, uitextfield

I´m new to Objective C and learn it on my own with a book. I have a some `UITextFields` in which the user is supposed to enter some numbers. These numbers can be used to calculate the volume of a variation of bodies. The problem is, that if I want to use the `UITextField` XCode always gives me a warning:

> Incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing `UITextField *__weak` to parameter of type `int`

So I looked up how to convert a string into a number. I tried `NSNumberFormatter` and also changing it to a number by using

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"f", Width];
```

The variable `Width` is the variable defined in the calculator class later on. Still the warning message was something similar to the previous one. I searched pretty long now so I just asked here.

How can I use the data given by the `UITextField`?

Thanks in advance for your help! If needed I can upload more of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed the problem :)
The solution was really simple. I just used:

double QWidthDouble = [_widthTextField.text doubleValue];

calculator.QWidth = QWidthDouble;

Now my class variable QWidth gets a double from the text field.
I hope my question can help someone :)